# Show that $\int_0^{2 \pi}\vert rie^{it}\vert dt=2 \pi r$

Tags: calculus, integration

I am struggling with an normally simple integral calculation. I wanna show:
$$\int_0^{2 \pi}\vert rie^{it}\vert dt=2 \pi r$$
I tried the following:
$\int_0^{2\pi}\vert rie^{it}\vert dt=\vert ri \vert \int_0^{2\pi}\vert e^{it}\vert dt = $r$ *(\vert e^{(2 \pi i)} \vert- \vert e^{0} \vert)=0$...

Where is my mistake? Thanks for your help.

Comment: $\lvert e^{it} \rvert  = 1$.

Comment: Recall that $e^{it}=\cos t + i\sin t$.

Comment: Your mistake was in assuming that  
$$
\int |f(t)|dt = 
\left| \int f(t) dt\right|
$$

Comment: Sorry, when did I assumed this @BenGrossmann? I don't see it...

Comment: @FrederickManfred How did you go from $\int_0^{2 \pi}|e^{it}|dt$ to $|e^{2 \pi i}| - |e^0|$?

Comment: True, thank you I just saw my mistake!

Comment: $\displaystyle 2\pi\color{red}{\left\vert\color{black}{r}\right\vert}$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

since $|r|=r, |i|=1, |e^{it}|=1$, $$I=\int_{0}^{2\pi} |ri e^{it}| dt=\int_{0}^{2\pi} r dt=2\pi r.$$

Answer (score 0):

$$|rie^{it}|=|r|\times|ie^{it}|=r\times1=r$$
so you have:
$$\int_0^{2\pi}rdt=2\pi r$$
this is because $e^{it}$ represents a unit circle in the complex domain, so the modulus i.e. the radius from origin of a complex point, is always 1